# SQL: How to get salary format of “$99,999.00”

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In my table, the salary is in format "99999", how do I get it/select it into the format of “$99,999.00”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a format mask like the one below. Different format models can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-24E16D8D-25E4-4BD3-A38D-CE1399F2897C).

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR (99999, 'FM$999,999,999.00') AS formatted_num FROM DUAL;


   FORMATTED_NUM
________________
$99,999.00
```